# how to resolve the issues on eclipse when using robotium?

Tags: android, eclipse, robotium

I have downloaded sometimes back eclipse helios and installed ADT.  I am getting the option Android Project under Android.[image]

After my system crash again i am downloading the same eclipse and installed ADT but not getting the same option as i got earlier (screenshot attached) .. and also earlier i have to create package but this time automatically package is getting created.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also seen this previously.

"Android Project" and "Android Application Project" are same.

I use latest "ADT 20.0.3 plugin (August 2012)".

[image]

I try to create one Android Project using option " Android Application Project "
and it work for me.

I hope this will work for you. Thanks.

Note:
just for your information, I use " Android Test Project " for robotium to test other android projects.